How to use 2 different psb in one GameObject in Unity?
I've been facing this issue for days and I couldn't find any solution.
I have one GameObject for the main character. I also created 2 different psb files, one for when the character is idle and anotherone for when it's moving, and animated them ussing bones in the skinning editor in a way that the running psb has more/different named bones than the idle one.
The thing is that I want to use one psb for animating an idle motion, and another different one for animating the character running, as using the same for both animations would look worse.
In addition, I have an Animation Controller with 2 states, Idle and Running, and the transition between the 2 is done by setting a variable in my Character controller. When executing the game and moving, I can see in the Animator tab that the transition is made between the states and that both animations are playing only when they are intended to, but in the Game tab the character is only performing the starting animation.
I've tried somehow adding the 2 psb files to the game object, but I'm stucked on how can I swap them in the Character Controller. Also, I don't know if that's the correct way, as changing them in the controller wouldn't need an animation controller that orchestrates the different animations and that seems wrong.
Can someone point me in the right direction?
Thank you all.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The correct answer is likely to use a single psb file.  Maintaining two (or more?) separate files for animating a single character seems cumbersome and incorrect (when wanting to blend those animations).  Is there a specific reason the idle needs a different bone structure?
